# React Router Url Giving Bad Request

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am facing a issue in routing. 
the issue is when i hit the url - http://localhost:3000/extInsurance/16/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySUQiOiIzIiwiUm9sZUlEIjoiOCIsIlVzZXJOYW1lIjoiYWxpY2lhaGludG9uQHlvcG1haWwuY29tIiwiQ2xpbmljSUQiOiIxMjg5IiwiVXNlclR5cGUiOiJTVEFGRiIsIlN0YWZmSUQiOiIyIiwiUm9sZU5hbWUiOiJET0NUT1IiLCJCdXNpbmVzc1Rva2VuIjoiYmxvb2QwMDEiLCJPcmdJRCI6IjEzNTYiLCJCYXNlUm9sZUlEIjoiOCIsIkJhc2VVc2VyVHlwZSI6IlNUQUZ

this url get hits properly and i get the response. meaning i get redirect to correct page.
but when i push this on testing server then i am getting bad request with same url

also when i reduce the path then again it get hit properly on my testing server.

Comment: What exactly is the error code?

Comment: Bad Request - Invalid URL

Comment: Please provide the piece of code that malfunctions.

Comment: i dont know what's going wrong. 
when i hit the same url from localhost it redirects me to that path correctly. but when i hit the path from my testing server it shows invalid URL

Comment: is there any character count that is allowed in the path name ?

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea to use token as a part of URL path. 
It's recommended to pass token as a optional URL parameter. Something like this,

```
http://localhost:3000/some-path?token=eyJhb...
```

Comment: how to do it in react js ?